# Strange Javascript / jQuery Issue - Assigning and reading values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

I've been working with jQuery for going on 2 years now, and I know this is simple, I've done it many times before, but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to work today, so I'm posting here.  Here is my Javascript code snipped:

```
(function () {

        // checking for query strings
        var vars = [], hash;
        var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
        if (q != undefined) {
            q = q.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
                hash = q[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[1]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
        }
        // end query string check

        // using query strings above to perform operations
        if (typeof (vars['grade']) != "undefined") {
            alert(vars['grade']);
            $('#divGrade').html(vars['grade']);
        }

        alert($('#divGrade').html());

    })();
```

and I've got a div tag on the page:
`<div id="divGrade" ></div>`

and the query string is: `default.html?grade=0`

The javascript reads the grade, which is 0, and then with the "alert" it shows it to the user, it then assigns it to the div tag.  When trying to alert the user of the html of the div tag, it's "undefined".

I've been staring at this, and I know it's something stupid that I'm doing.  Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: i doubt about this part 
vars.push(hash[1]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
you are adding [1] => value to array and then trying to set by key

Comment: You use `(function() { ... })();` did you mean to use `$(function() { ... });` ?  What do you get with `alert($('#divGrade').length)` (ie is it on the page *when you run* the code?)

Comment: Your code is fine, the problem is that `Document.URL` does not contain the search parameters. Do a `console.log(document.URL);` They could be found in `window.location.search`, do a `console.log(window.location.search)` on that and see what you get.

Comment: @Fran they are included (in Chrome at least).  `((location.href == document.URL) == true)`

Comment: Feels there are some external reason that caused this issue, the code looks fine. maybe there are some other scope issue?

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, for me `location.href == document.URL` is also true but for me `href` as well as `URL` both don't contain the values of and after `?` in chrome, when testing on `plunkr` It could be OPs website does some funny business too, hence my suggestion to OP to `console.log(document.URL)`

Comment: @Fran ok, my example not very help if your location.href also doesn't include the search - however it *should*.  If plunkr works like jsfiddle then it won't have any search anyway (guessing) - try it in the console on a real website (that has `?` ofc).   OP does mention that the search value is `alert`d to the user, so likely ok at that point.

Comment: @freedomn-m You are right, I didn't realize jsfiddle or plunkr do that.

Comment: Thanks for all the input!  Turns out the code I had wasn't working because I had a select statement elsewhere on the page (didn't include it becuase I didn't think it was relevant), and I was autoclosing the select like <select id="ddl1" /> instead of <select id="ddl1" ></select>.

Answer (score 0):

```
// checking for query strings 
var vars = {},
  hash;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if (q != undefined) {
  q = q.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    hash = q[i].split('=');
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
}
```

`Vars["grade"]` requires vars to be an object not an array. An object has no push function.

Comment: Please test OPs code in JSFiddle or similar and check comments on question for possible explanations.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with it working, I can't get it to work.

Comment: An answer must not contain a full working example. Ive found a major mistake in the users code, and took time to write an answer. Downvoting is just unfair, unless the code/answer has wrong content

Comment: Didn't downvote, but this part *"The javascript reads the grade, which is 0, and then with the "alert" it shows it to the user*" indicates that the area you've provided an answer to is not the area where the issue is.

Comment: @freedomn-m Again. Not. A. Full.Answer.

Comment: @Jonasw I don't understand that comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is.

1: you are trying to use the object Bracket notation on vars but its an Array. Change it to object.

```js
(function() {

  // checking for query strings
  var url = "default.html?grade=0";
  var vars = {},
    hash;
  var q = url.split('?')[1];
  if (q != undefined) {

  
      q = q.split('&');

      for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        hash = q[i].split('=');
         
         vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
  }
  // end query string check

  // using query strings above to perform operations
  if (typeof(vars['grade']) != "undefined") {
    alert(vars['grade']);
    $('#divGrade').html(vars['grade']);
  }

  alert($('#divGrade').html());

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divGrade"></div>
```

Comment: Oouch .. downvoting wihout reason?

Comment: did you not see all the downvotes on the other questions, with no comment?  (not me)

Comment: hmmm serial down voting then :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val("Glenn Quagmire");
    });

   $('#myselect').change(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user"></p>

<button>Set the value of the input field</button>


<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
    <option value="2">Ram</option>
    <option value="3">david</option>
    <option value="4">Scott</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>

enter code here

</body>
</html>
```